# How to check whether a string pattern is present in a hive table column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am using the Cloudera cluster containing Hive-0.13.1 for my day-to-day activities.

I have few string patterns with me and I need to find whether any of these patterns are present in one of the columns in Hive table.

Example: The string patterns I have is short names of cricketers such as "Dravid", "Sachin", "Ganguly". I have a column in the hive which contains the full names of all the cricketers.

```
select full_name from players limit 3;

Rahul Dravid
Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar
Sourav Ganguly
```

I need to compare my string patterns with the values returned by my query and create another column with "Y" if it matches or with "N" if it doesn't match.

How to write Hive query to accomplish this apart from Regex?

Comment: you can use `like`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Case statement** with **like, or operators**

in the below query i have used **lower function** on full_name field and compared the data in the filed with lower names(dravid,sachin).

**Query:-**

```
select full_name, 
case 
    lower(full_name) like '%dravid%' 
or 
    lower(full_name) like '%ganguly%' 
or 
    lower(full_name) like '%sachin%' 
    then 'Y' 
else 'N' 
end new_column_name 
from players limit 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version of @Shu answer using conditional function `if` and relational operator `RLIKE` for regular expression matching:

```
SELECT full_name, 
if((lower(full_name) RLIKE 'dravid|sachin|ganguly'), 'Y', 'N') AS is_match
FROM players;
```